# click module autocomplete does not work at a depth of 3 groups

Tags: python, bash, autocomplete, command-line-interface, python-click

[`click`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/click) is a Python package for creating command line interfaces.

I have this command structure.

```
cli        (group - entry point)
-ip        (group)
--static   (group)
---foo     (method)
--floating (group)
---bar     (method)
```

And when I press <kbd>`Tab`</kbd><kbd>`Tab`</kbd> keys:

1. attempt - i have correct autocomplete such as `ip` command
2. attempt - i have correct autocomplete such as `floating` and `static` commands
3. attempt - i have **incorrect** autocomplete - list of all files in current dir instead of `bar` command.

[image: screenshot]

Here's the code:
**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='sampleclick',
    packages=['sampleclick'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'sc = sampleclick.shell:cli'
        ]
    },
    install_requires=[
        'click>=6.6',
    ]
)
```

**shell.py**

```
# coding=utf-8
import click


@click.group()
def cli():
    """Entry point"""


@cli.group()
def ip():
    pass


@ip.group()
def floating():
    pass


@floating.command()
def bar():
    """Is a ip floating command"""


@ip.group()
def static():
    pass


@static.command()
def foo():
    """Is a ip static command"""
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this bug in Click version 6.6. I can attest that it is fixed for me in version 6.7 by the following commit: https://github.com/pallets/click/commit/8af7ec14f3d936e02c2e4ee62d3573593868e07e.